# Cannot highlight a particular table row on button click from the same row

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

So I have a system that deactivates a certain contract on a table whenever it is on or after the expiry or end date. [Here is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C9mr.png)

What I wish to achieve is to just highlight a particular single table row that needs to be highlighted to indicate "deactivated" upon button click.

I have already tried the following solutions which unfortunately did not work for me:

```js
/*   WORKS, BUT ONLY ONE ROW HIGHLIGHTED AND CANNOT HIGHLIGHT NTH ROWS  */
function selectRow() {
  document.querySelector("input[type='button']").addEventListener('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatablesSimple">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Solicitor</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Days to Go</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy1</td>
      <td>2022-10-20</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deac" value="Deactivate" onclick="selectRow();" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy2</td>
      <td>2022-4-26</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deac" value="Deactivate" onclick="selectRow();" /></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
/*             WORKS, BUT ONCLICK NEEDS TO BE DOUBLE-CLICKED          */
function selectRow() {
  $('td input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatablesSimple">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Solicitor</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Days to Go</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy1</td>
      <td>2022-10-20</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deac" value="Deactivate" onclick="selectRow();" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy2</td>
      <td>2022-4-26</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deac" value="Deactivate" onclick="selectRow();" /></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
/*             WORKS, BUT ALL ROWS ARE HIGHLIGHTED               */
function selectRow() {
  var tbl = document.querySelector("table tbody");
  [...tbl.rows].forEach(el => {
    el.classList.toggle('table-danger');
  });
}
```

```css
.table-danger {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatablesSimple">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Solicitor</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Days to Go</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy1</td>
      <td>2022-10-20</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deac" value="Deactivate" onclick="selectRow();" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy2</td>
      <td>2022-4-26</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deac" value="Deactivate" onclick="selectRow();" /></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your first example seems good, but it's got `onclick="selectRow()/></td>` at the end. That should be:  `onclick="selectRow();"></td>`

Comment: Thank you, @KIKOSoftware But unfortunately, after correcting the syntax, it is still not working.

Comment: If you want us to understand what your problem is, and if you want to enable us to help you, you will have to supply a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We know you use JQuery, we see the several Javascript attempts, but we haven't got the HTML nor do we know how it all hangs together.

Comment: Hi! I apologize as I am still new to this community. I already edited my code above, hopefully it follows the Minimal Reproducible Example. @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Your second example is the recommended approach, but remove the `onclick=selectedRow` from the HTML and remove the `function selected()` wrapper - ie just `$('td input[type="button"]').on('click', function() { $(this)... })`;

Comment: Issue with first:  `querySelector` is the same as `querySelectorAll().first()` - so only applies to the first row.  Though you'll *also* have the same issue as your second attempt - the need to click twice.   Your 3 approach selects all rows and adds the class, so it's a little surprising that you find this surprising that it applies to all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this...

```
function selectRow() {
  $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
  });
}
```

...to this.

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

See the snippet below.

```js
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatablesSimple">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Solicitor</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Days to Go</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy1</td>
      <td>2022-10-20</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deac" value="Deactivate"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy2</td>
      <td>2022-4-26</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deac" value="Deactivate"/></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked and what I've been looking for. Thank you!